# How to convert createQuery response in key value pair?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, createquery

I am using createQuery function in my application. below is the sample code.

```
   String test = "select t.name,t.descr,t.category from Test t where t.companyId=companyId";

    List<Object[]> object = entityManager.createQuery(hql.toString())
            .setParameter("companyId", 9001).getResultList();
```

So as of now response coming in list of objects. columns names are not coming in response , directly values are coming.

i need response in key value pair, something like that below sample..
  if three rows coming from query then response should be

```
   {"name":"test","descr":"test descr", "category":"test category"}
   {"name":"test","descr":"test descr", "category":"test category"}
   {"name":"test","descr":"test descr", "category":"test category"}
```

Actually query will be coming dynamically in createQuery method, that's why i don't know what are the columns will be there in query.

That's why i need response in key value pair.

Comment: So you need  to parse the query string using regular expression for instance and extract the column names before mapping your list of Object[] to a list of Map

Comment: Your response looks like JSON. Do you want JSON?